# How to use ParseExact format when adb shell date returned value with multiple formats

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, adb, uitest

`adb shell date` returned the string : Wed May 18 19:18:08 IST 2022

I am able to parse this string using

```
DateTime currentdateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(deviceCurrentDateTime, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'IST' yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But when adb shell date returned the string : Thu May  5 19:18:01 IST 2022 (two spaces after May)

then above parseExact is not working.

How to use multiple formats to parse the two dates?

Comment: why it has `xamarin.android` tag ? are you using xamarin? then why you are using `adb shell date`  instead `DateTime.Now` ?if not then why you are using this tag ?

Comment: Just to be SUPER clear, you're saying the date your getting is 'Thu May  5 19:18:01 IST 2022' with TWO spaces after May? I don't know who came up with that one

Comment: @Selvin , I am working on Xamarin UITest Automation where i have to get the mobile device date using adb shell date command and parse the date -> add no of days to this date -> set back the new date(future date) to my rooted device. that's is reason i have used Xamarin.android tag and i can't utilize DateTime.Now , as it doesn't return the date from my rooted device.

Comment: Why don't you use the command-line options of `date` to specify the format you want? E.g. `adb shell date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this where you replace your double space with a single space. Usually you'd expect to see a 0 rather than a space in most cases, but hey ho.

```
var deviceCurrentDateTime = "Thu May  5 19:18:01 IST 2022";
deviceCurrentDateTime = deviceCurrentDateTime.Replace("  ", " ");
DateTime currentdateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(deviceCurrentDateTime, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss 'IST' yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note I've also replaced your format string with "ddd MMM **d** HH:mm:ss 'IST' yyyy"

EDIT:

Example where it's working

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var deviceCurrentDateTime = "Thu May  5 19:18:01 IST 2022";
    deviceCurrentDateTime = deviceCurrentDateTime.Replace("  ", " ");
    DateTime currentdateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(deviceCurrentDateTime, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss 'IST' yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(currentdateTime.ToString());
}
```

Prints: 05/05/2022 19:18:01

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var deviceCurrentDateTime = "Wed May 18 19:18:01 IST 2022";
    deviceCurrentDateTime = deviceCurrentDateTime.Replace("  ", " ");
    DateTime currentdateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(deviceCurrentDateTime, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss 'IST' yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(currentdateTime.ToString());
}
```

Prints: 18/05/2022 19:18:01

Comment: if i use "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss 'IST' yyyy" then Wed May 18 19:18:08 IST 2022 will fail

Comment: Works for me, see my answer. Potentially you may have an extra space at the end of your string? Put '.Trim()' at the end of '.Replace()'